# Problemas em fazer listagem por usuário usando Ionic e Firebase

Tags: ionic, firebase

Olá

Estou tentando elaborar um aplicativo utilizando Ionic e Firebase, porém estou com dificuldades de conseguir fazer uma listagem por usuários. O app já possui cadastro de usuários e o cadastro dos produtos que quero listar, porém não consigo listar somente os produtos do próprio usuário que o cadastrou.

Alguma ideia de como posso resolver?

Comment: Mas quando cria um usuário no banco ele não ganha um id único? Então, é só filtrar os produtos de cada usuário pelo seu id.

Answer (score 0):

Por favor coloque o código relevante, mas não teria muito segredo, no modelo produto tem o cliente ou o cliente tem os produtos dependendo a modelagem.